# Accessing x-modal data and storing in database

Tags: php, database, laravel, xcode, alpine.js

I am having some trouble accessing x-model data in my laravel app and storing it into my database. Wondering if anyone can help.

So the issue seems to be coming from the fact that I have the category select as a separate blade that I call multiple times.

[image]

So ultimately, this code is called three times on my main page. I can then choose three separate categories - but when I try to call those selections and store them in database I run into an error.

Wondering if anyone has any ideas how to access the three separate categories being selected and add them to database. Some links or documentation to check out would be mighty helpful!

Using alpinejs, php, and laravel.

EDIT
In this particular case I am passing the information into the blade through the controller.

[image]

EDIT 2:this shows $selection_id
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`x-model` takes the **name** of a variable inside `x-data`, **not the value**.

`$selection_id` here is a value.

You should do something like:

```
x-data="{ selection_id: {{$selection_id}} }"
```

on the component element

then inside x-model:
x-model="selection_id"

> Note: Your code is missing, please add the part with the `x-data showing.

Comment: I added the data into my original post. It should be noted that I just pass the information into the blade through the controller.

Comment: @JacobDowns I think you're passing it as a value, you can't control PHP variables from the client side with Alpine.js. What is $selection_id? is it like an integer or the name of a variable (string)?
You can get help from more people in the [Discord server](https://discord.gg/Q8UpvXje) if you can join

Comment: Ah, interesting. I think I see the issue. I made one extra update so you can see what selection_id is...

Comment: Right it's a value, it's confusing since it's a mix of server side rendering and client side.
You should make a javascript variable that hold the selection_id instead
To sync it with the server that's a hard part, but since you're using Laravel, look at this: https://github.com/radio-js/radio